# How do I traverse layerSets & artLayers in Extendscript?

Tags: extendscript, photoshop-script

I'm familiar with CSS selectors and traversing in jQuery but can't work out how to do it in ExtendScript. I want to find the second to last folder in a layerSet and then go to the first LayerSet within it and select/focus it. I can't see how to go up and down PhotoShop's DOM (other than layerSets.length), nor how to specify a specific layerSets/artLayers without using names. Here's my lame attempt with made up stuff to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

```
var topFolders = app.activeDocument.layerSets.length; //how many folders
var todayFolder = layerSetID(topFolders-1); //totally made up layerSetID()
app.activeDocument.activeLayer = todayFolder; //make folder active
```

I've been trawling photoshop_scriptref_js.pdf looking up things to do with name, index, select but can't find anything that I can understand fits my issue.

Comment: I kept digging around and found the essence of my question in this Adobe forum question... the answer of which broke me - I will no longer be trying to do PS Automation :( https://forums.adobe.com/message/7491752

Comment: In a nutshell: it's ugly! There's no nice way of doing this apart from re-iterating over the layers till it finds the one you want. Accessing them by name (isn't hat you want) but is a lot easier: 
srcDoc.activeLayer = srcDoc.layerSets.getByName("myGroup").artLayers.getByName("my layer 2");

Comment: Unfortunately the name changes each week but yes, it would have been easier. I then resorted to just using the selected folder but still got all tangle up. The process I was trying to automate wasn't worth the learning curve.

Comment: Initially before I got my head around traversing layers, groups and sub groups I used to run "destructive" scripts that would firstly get rid of all layer groups first and then access the layer I wanted secondly.